# See which of several radio buttons are checked (per column)

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I created a project ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/azarew/tr2xtwje/)) where I have a table with each column representing a different event. The first column has the hours. I want the user to select a different number of cells, per column, according to the duration of the event on a certain day. For example, if the user wanted to say he slept from 9 a.m to 11 a.m he would select the first three cells from column one.

The results from my search only indicated how to check if one radio button was selected. I tried the `console.log($(this).val());` line of code however nothing shows up in my console.

How can I get the information of which cells were checked, per column?

Answer (score 0):

To all of you interested in this question I have the solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/azarew/bbyun8eu/).

```
var s= [];
```

The algorith is creating an array of values chosen per column in the console and organizing each cell by ascending order.

Good luck!